# Cassandra system disk full

Tags: cassandra, diskspace

After starting Cassandra and starting batch writes, the system disk becomes full and when I inspect it using `df -h`. But I can't find the which files use this space used. I tried to inspect using `du -h` with no success. After restarting the machine, the problem still exists.

When I delete some files and start Cassandra again I got about 11GB available?

Any advice to got a solution for this problem?

Thanks

Comment: how big are the batches your doing? are you distributing the load or going through the 1 coordinator for everything?

Comment: We write about 2M records per hour. and the servers are AWS with 15GB for system disk.

Answer (score 0):

For data and commit log files see these places. You can configure these in cassandra.yaml file.

**data_file_directories** 
The directory location where table data (SSTables) is stored. Cassandra distributes data evenly across the location, subject to the granularity of the configured compaction strategy. Default locations:

Package installations: /var/lib/cassandra/data

Tarball installations: install_location/data/data

**commitlog_directory** 
The directory where the commit log is stored. Default locations:

Package installations: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog

Tarball installations: install_location/data/commitlog

For more information [read this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html).

Comment: Thanks @Bhathia, but we already set these directories to another disk.